# Setting the field values to be returned to Splunk server using java

Tags: events, field, splunk

I am using java rest api sdk to retrieve events from the Splunk's search app. I retrieved the field called splunk_server during search time and i set the value for it. Then i tried to format the log message in a key=value pair pattern. eg. splunk_server=remoteserver. I wanted the value for the splunk_server that i set to appear for the new event added to splunk. But the default value appeared instead.

Is there any way to set the value for the splunk_server and show the value i set in Splunk server whenever i add new events?

Answer (score 0):

There are two pivots on this.  First at search time you can enrich events.  This is done in a lot of lookup scenarios.  For example, at search time you can add the field splunk_server based on the value of another field that is persisted in Splunk.  That new field, however, would not get persisted in Splunk.  It would just be piped to the results of your search.

Then there is the ability to add data into splunk and create an additional field and set that value.  splunk_server is not a special field in Splunk and you could definitely do that at ingest time.

Our developer site has more info on the Java SDK:  http://dev.splunk.com/view/java-sdk/SP-CAAAECN

More details in the question though would be helpful.